# TypeError: fn is not a function - but I didn't write fn in my file

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have no idea how this happened, I was just working on my code when all of a sudden, I get an error from another file! I didn't write fn anywhere in the file I was working in. The file I am working in is `C:/Users/---/Discord Bot/index.js` but I got the error from `C:/Users/---/Discord Bot/node_modules/@discordjs/collection/dist/index.js - line 161 col 17` and I did see `if(fn(val, key, this))` on that line but I changed NOTHING in that file, I didn't even know it existed before now. What do I do? Another `npm install discord.js`? I only recently got it anyways.
Here's the full error message in case you might need it.

```
    at Map.find (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:161:17)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\index.js:394:56)
    at Client.emit (node:events:381:22)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\---\Discord Bot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:369:20)
```

Comment: It may also mean that something you wrote is passing a not-function where a function was expected. If it happened "all of a sudden" it's likely your code.

Comment: Can you post your code? It will be a `.find()` method somewhere in there.

Comment: The find method is at line 394, column 56. You need to call find with a function that accepts `value`, `key`, and `collection` and returns a boolean.

Comment: Yes ok now I know which it is, I removed it and now the error is gone, thanks!

Comment: The part of the error message you pasted in is called the stack trace. It says what javascript was doing when it ran into the error, from the last thing it was doing down. The first line is in the @discordjs/collection module, the next line is your code. It's very useful for debugging to follow the stack trace until you find your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So re-installing discord.js won't help you. the `fn` on that line get's set by *you* on *your* index.js

**For Example** you perhaps run `message.channel.find(VARIABLE)` `fn` gets set to `VARIABLE` and then it tries to runs `fn` as a function even if `VARIABLE` isn't a function.

Now I do not know where `fn` get's set (*too lazy to check through the code*), but it does get set by you when you pass in a variable.

***My guess*** is that it's on line `394` of YOUR `index.js` as that's when a chain of actions happen leading to `fn` being called.

This is about the best one can do without your code, and full error. You've given us the trace not the error. And without your code related to `index.js#394` we can't help further.